# How to change the database for usage and health data collection service

Tags: 2013, site-usage, health-analyzer

how to change the the database for usage and health data collection service in sharepoint 2013, now its database size is 50 GB and i want to change the database size.

Comment: you want to create new database and attach to it or you want to increase the size of current db?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a new Database to Usage and Health data collection service.

To point the Usage and Health Data Collection service application to a moved database by using Central Administration

1. Verify that the user account that is performing the procedure is a
   member of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
2. In Central Administration, click **Monitoring**, and then on the
   Monitoring page, click **Configure usage and health data collection**.

   The Configure web analytics and health data collection page appears.
3. Clear the **Enable health data collection** check box, and then click
   OK.

   You return to the Monitoring page.
4. Click **Configure usage and health data collection** to return to the
   Configure web analytics and health data collection page.
5. Select the **Enable health data collection** check box
6. In the **Logging Database Server** section, specify the database
   server and database name, and then click **OK.**

Or user powershell:

```
Set-SPUsageApplication -Identity "<ServiceApplicationName>" -DatabaseName "<DbName>" -DatabaseServer "<SQLServerName>"
```

Where:

- ServiceApplicationName> is the name of the usage and health data
  collection service application.
- DbName> is the name of the database.
- SQLServerName> is the name of the database server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729804.aspx